# Where is the MARKUP that I can actually edit?

Tags: magento-1.8, html

This is likely a duplicate question, but I honestly cannot find a good answer for where in your Magento install you find actual markup that resembles what you see on the actual site.

I've checked countless .xml files and .phtml files, but can find no reference to 'topSearch' anywhere. Is there some kind of logic that I am missing? Is this some elaborate joke? Is this complexity really necessary?

This:

```
<div class="grid_4">
  <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
</div>
```

Renders this:

```
<div class="grid_4">
  <form id="search_mini_form" action="XXXX" method="get">
    <div class="form-search">
      <div class="search-wrap">
        <input type="text" name="q" value="" class="input-text" maxlength="128">
        <button id="search" type="submit" class="button" value="Search entire store here..." autocomplete="off"><span class="btn-img"></span></button>
      </div>
      <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete" style="display: none;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And I can't find where the markup is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to `theme/layout/catalogsearch.xml` and search for `topSearch` then you will find this block:

```
<default>
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    ...........
```

This fairly says your template is `catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml`.

**To check which html is rendered from which template file, you can turn your phtml path hint on. [Learn here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273443/in-magento-1-9-0-0-how-can-i-enable-template-path-hint)**

Comment: Thank you. I found the HTML. Is there any logic to this, or you just happen to know where that particular file lives?

Comment: Great, you can turn your **template path hint ON** to know which files are where. For me, I kind of get the idea where they might be.

Comment: Also, I found this file in the default template, so don't forget to look there, I guess.

Comment: You also need to understand magento **fall back** system. First magento looks to your active theme then if not found goes to **default** then not found goes to **base**.

Comment: I understand there is a fallback system, but without Path Hints, there doesn't seem to be a way to know which template to look in.